# Difference between Expression Engine Weblog and Channel?

Tags: expressionengine

With Expression Engine, whats the difference between Weblog and Channel pairs? Is Channel just the name for the same thing in v2?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Channel just the name for the same thing in v2?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionEngine 1.x — and its former code base pMachine Pro — naïvely distinguished a collection of data stored in the database as a "weblog".

This nomenclature was used widely throughout the Control Panel and naming of Modules, right down to the the [Weblog Entries Tag](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/modules/weblog/weblog_entries.html) used in templates.

**ExpressionEngine 1.x Weblog Entries Tag:**

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="portfolio"}
    <p>{title}</p>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

As the publishing needs of web sites evolved and ExpressionEngine itself matured, EllisLab recognized that calling everything a "weblog" was silly (to put it into my own words) and didn't reflect real world use.

So with the release of [ExpressionEngine 2.x Public Beta](http://expressionengine.com/blog/entry/expressionengine_2.0_public_beta_now_live/) in December 2009, *weblogs* were officially renamed to *channels*, starting with EE 2.0, Build 20091202.

Using the code snippet above, you'll see the usage of `weblogs` was renamed to `channels`:

**ExpressionEngine 2.x Channel Entries Tag:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="portfolio"}
    <p>{title}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This change in nomenclature positions ExpressionEngine from being viewed as simply a *Blogging Tool* into a more robust *Publishing Platform* or CMS (Content Management System).